# What is the conjugation of 「悲しきかな」?

Tags: conjugations

Saw this in a blog post: 「悲しきかな読書への愛を育むほどに、夢は現実から遠ざかる」
It seems like 「悲しきかな」is used as a na-adjective (形容動詞). Is this correct? I've never seen this form of adjective before, what would its conjugation be?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not an independent adjective, but can be divided as 悲しき + かな, where 悲しき is a classical 連体形 (pre-noun form) and [かな](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA/#jn-43372) is a particle

> 体言・活用語の連体形に付いて、感動・詠嘆を表す。…だなあ。

> *Preceded by nouns or pre-noun form, indicates being impressed/exclamation. Translated as* だなあ.

So a modern version would be 悲しいなあ, meaning *oh, how sad...*