# Use of "かな" in these Bashō/Sora haiku

Tags: grammar, japanese-to-english, classical-japanese, archaic-language, haiku

First: I am a beginner. I don't know much.

So, I am reading おくのほそ道. I am confused by the use of かな in these haiku:

田一枚植えて立ち去る柳かな

and

卯の花をかざしに関のはれぎかな

I have been told かな conveys uncertainty and wondering, but I cannot see what is uncertain in these particular cases. How should I understand these uses of かな as an English speaker?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

かな in modern colloquial Japanese means "I wonder" or "...no?", but this type of かな never appears in classical literature. When you see かな in haiku, it's almost always an exclamatory particle similar in purpose to "O", "oh" or "!" in English.

- [What is the conjugation of 「悲しきかな」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90506/5010)

The corresponding entry on jisho.org seems to be [this](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%93%89). It's a little hard to find a natural equivalent of this type of かな in modern Japanese, but it would be "(～である)なあ" or "～よ".